# Create a default vhost to serve http request in uwsgi

Tags: python, http, uwsgi

I've uwsgi 2.0.19 on Linux running with the python plugin. I serve http(s) traffic with different applications each for a specific record of my managed domain using such kind of configuration to register them to the front uwsgi servers.

```
subscribe2 = server=x.x.x.x:4443,key=domain.com,sni_key=/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key,sni_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
subscribe2 = server=x.x.x.x:4443,key=domain.com:443,sni_key=/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key,sni_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
subscribe2 = server=y.y.y.y:4443,key=domain.com,sni_key=/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key,sni_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
subscribe2 = server=y.y.y.y:4443,key=domain.com:443,sni_key=/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key,sni_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
```

Now when I reach one of the front servers to access a not-existing host, I received such  error (the TCP connexion is closed I assume)

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I would like to be able to have a default/catchall key for such case, that permits to return an HTTP status 404 as I would do in Apache using the `_default_` vhost. is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement this, you need to define a fallback application using the `http-subscription-fallback-key` on the front uwsgi server

```
http-subscription-fallback-key=default
```

`default` is a standard application registered on the frontal uwsgi like any other application

```
subscribe2 = server=x.x.x.x:4443,key=default
subscribe2 = server=x.x.x.x:4443,key=default:80
```